# Adding features in a vector source using openlayers 5

Tags: openlayers

I'm fairly embarrassed by this question, as I suspect I'm missing something very obvious. I'm trying to render programmatically generated features in a vector source but the three point geometries in the 'features' array are not being displayed. (see the code below)

- I'm feeding the coordinates as a string (this is what is advised in the [API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_coordinate.html#~Coordinate)). I've also tried to pass them as an array of two float elements, but did not work.
- The three features and 'features' array are being properly created as I have access to them in the console.
- The features are indeed not being added as the 'addfeature' event is not being fired.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css"
        type="text/css">
    <style>
        .map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 800px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>

    <title>OpenLayers example</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // I wish to render in the vector layer the following three features            
        const features = [

            new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point('29.630329200, 36.204621700'), // this string is exactly the output of ol.coordinate.toStringXY
                time: '2019-03-17 09:43:31.428',
                TWS: 5.29
            }),

            new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point('29.630280100, 36.204555700'),
                time: '2019-03-17 09:43:31.428',
                TWS: 3.50
            }),

            new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point('29.630290700, 36.204584000'),
                time: '2019-03-17 09:45:31.983',
                TWS: 1.50
            }),

        ];


        const topoMap = new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
                url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer'
            })
        });

        const baseOSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });

        const view = new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([29.630329200, 36.204621700]),
            zoom: 14
        });

        const sailingTrack = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                // as per the API documentation this should be enough to render the features               
                features: features
            })
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [baseOSM, topoMap, sailingTrack],
            view: view
        });

        // The line below doesn't load the features either
        sailingTrack.getSource().addFeatures(features);

        // The event below never fires, hence the features are not being added            
        sailingTrack.getSource().on('addfeature', function () {

            console.log('addfeature fired');
            map.getView().fit(sailingTrack.getSource().getExtent());

        });

    </script
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `ol.geom.Point` expects a coordinate array (similar to `ol.proj.fromLonLat`) so you don;t need to convert it with `toStringXY`  but it does need to be in view projection `new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([29.630329200, 36.204621700]))`

Comment: Thanks Mike, it worked. However, the 'addfeature' event is not firing. It fires if I declare for the source the param 'url' pointing to a gpx file, and 'format' ```ol.format.GPX()```. By using the features approach (code above) the callback function bound to 'addfeature' does not seem to execute.

Comment: Features specified when you create the source won't fire an event (only features added subsequently do that, and you must set the listener **before** adding them) so you can call `map.getView()..fit(...)` as soon as the map is created without waiting for an event.